# How to annotate type using the splat operator

Tags: julia, splat

How (is it possible) to annotate the type of arguments when using the splat operator?

```
f(x, y) = x^2 + y^2
vec = [1.0, 2.0, 'a']
f(vec[1:2]...)
```

How can I annotate that use of `...` in the function call. Also notice that none of the macros to view code (`@code_llvm`, `@code_lowered`, `@code_native`, `@code_typed`, `@code_warntype`) work, so it would be very hard to optimize when using the splat?

Comment: Why do you think using splat on function call, prevent annotating types on function definition?

Comment: I didn't mean on a function definition, I mean on a function call. Suppose I annotated x and y above as Reals, but I happen to know that some elements in a vector to be spliced using splat are Integers, how I can type that splicing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it seems that in the above use-case, macro versions of reflection functions couldn't reach the right argument types, using original function instead of macro, could be helpful:

```
f(x, y) = x^2 + y^2
vec = [1.0, 2.0, 'a']
@code_warntype(f(vec[1:2]...)) # => Nothing
code_warntype(f,map(typeof,vec[1:2])) 
#  Variables:
#  x::Float64
#  y::Float64
#  .....
```

This logic is true for all reflection macros, using their variant function with a `(function, collection of types)`.

references:

1. The macro @code_warntype has function variant: [@code_warntype](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/performance-tips/#code-warntype)
2. How macros generated: [macro generator](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/232855ed8874f5d6615ab4512bcce33b71841e56/base/interactiveutil.jl#L289)
3. Util function to reach types: [gen_call_with_extracted_types](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/232855ed8874f5d6615ab4512bcce33b71841e56/base/interactiveutil.jl#L247)

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean something like this:

```rb
julia> foo(args::Float64...) = sum([x^2 for x in args])::Float64
foo (generic function with 1 method)

julia> foo(args::Vector{Float64}) = foo(args...)::Float64
foo (generic function with 2 methods)

julia> foo(args::Tuple{Vararg{Float64}}) = foo(args...)::Float64
foo (generic function with 3 methods)

julia> foo(2.0, 5.5, 7.0)
83.25

julia> v = Float64[2, 5.5, 7.0]
    3-element Array{Float64,1}:
     2.0
     5.5
     7.0

julia> foo(v)
83.25

julia> t = tuple(v...)
(2.0,5.5,7.0)

julia> foo(t)
83.25
```

I've placed type anotations in several places, so you can get the feel of the possibilities.

```rb
julia> @which foo(2.0, 5.5, 7.0)
foo(args::Float64...) at none:1

julia> @which foo(v)
foo(args::Array{Float64,1}) at none:1

julia> @which foo(t)
foo(args::Tuple{Vararg{Float64}}) at none:1
```

`@code_warntype`, etc.

```rb
julia> @code_warntype foo(2.0, 5.5, 7.0)
Variables:
  args::Tuple{Float64,Float64,Float64}
  #s33::Int64
  #s32::Int64
  #s31::Int64
  x::Float64
  #s30::Int64

Body:
  begin  # none, line 1:
      GenSym(1) = (Base.nfields)(args::Tuple{Float64,Float64,Float64})::Int64
      0:
      GenSym(3) = (top(ccall))(:jl_alloc_array_1d,(top(apply_type))(Base.Array,Float64,1)::Type{Array{Float64,1}},(top(svec))(Base.Any,Base.Int)::SimpleVector,Array{Flo
at64,1},0,GenSym(1),0)::Array{Float64,1}
      #s33 = 1
      #s32 = 1
      #s31 = 0
      unless (Base.box)(Base.Bool,(Base.not_int)(#s31::Int64 === GenSym(1)::Bool)::Any)::Bool goto 2
      3:
      #s31 = (Base.box)(Base.Int,(Base.add_int)(#s31::Int64,1)::Any)::Int64
      GenSym(10) = (Base.getfield)(args::Tuple{Float64,Float64,Float64},#s32::Int64)::Float64
      GenSym(11) = (Base.box)(Base.Int,(Base.add_int)(#s32::Int64,1)::Any)::Int64
      #s30 = 1
      GenSym(12) = GenSym(10)
      GenSym(13) = (Base.box)(Base.Int,(Base.add_int)(1,1)::Any)::Int64
      x = GenSym(12)
      #s30 = GenSym(13)
      GenSym(14) = GenSym(11)
      GenSym(15) = (Base.box)(Base.Int,(Base.add_int)(2,1)::Any)::Int64
      #s32 = GenSym(14)
      #s30 = GenSym(15)
      GenSym(4) = (Base.box)(Base.Float64,(Base.mul_float)(x::Float64,x::Float64)::Any)::Float64
      $(Expr(:type_goto, 0, GenSym(4)))
      $(Expr(:boundscheck, false))
      (Base.arrayset)(GenSym(3),GenSym(4),#s33::Int64)::Array{Float64,1}
      $(Expr(:boundscheck, :(Main.pop)))
      #s33 = (Base.box)(Base.Int,(Base.add_int)(#s33::Int64,1)::Any)::Int64
      4:
      unless (Base.box)(Base.Bool,(Base.not_int)((Base.box)(Base.Bool,(Base.not_int)(#s31::Int64 === GenSym(1)::Bool)::Any)::Bool)::Any)::Bool goto 3
      2:
      1:
      GenSym(8) = GenSym(3)
      return (Base._mapreduce)($(Expr(:new, :((top(getfield))(Base,:IdFun)::Type{Base.IdFun}))),$(Expr(:new, :((top(getfield))(Base,:AddFun)::Type{Base.AddFun}))),GenSy
m(8))::Float64
  end::Float64
```

---

```rb
julia> @code_warntype foo(v)
Variables:
  args::Array{Float64,1}

Body:
  begin  # none, line 1:
      return (top(_apply))((top(getfield))(Main,:call)::F,Main.foo,args::Array{Float64,1})::Float64
  end::Float64
```

---

```rb
julia> @code_warntype foo(t)
Variables:
  args::Tuple{Float64,Float64,Float64}

Body:
  begin  # none, line 1:
      return (Main.foo)((top(getfield))(args::Tuple{Float64,Float64,Float64},1)::Float64,(top(getfield))(args::Tuple{Float64,Float64,Float64},2)::Float64,(top(getfield))(args::Tuple{Float64,Float64,Float64},3)::Float64)::Float64
  end::Float64
```

**Edit:** IJulia notebook, tested at juliabox.org, Julia v0.4.1:

- http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/Ismael-VC/edeb2f919c2341cb389c

You can also put type annotations when calling a function:

```rb
julia> @which foo(t::Tuple{Vararg{Float64}}...)
foo(args::Tuple{Vararg{Float64}}) at none:1

julia> @which foo(v::Vector{Float64}...)
foo(args::Array{Float64,1}) at none:1
```

Comment: @which foo(v...) # => ERROR: ArgumentError: argument is not a generic function ....

Comment: @Reza Afzalan you must be doing something wrong, you should try again: `julia> @which foo(v...) # -> foo(args::Array{Float64,1}) at none:1`

Comment: Check out the answer again, I've added a link to an IJulia notebook.